# Showing Content type invalid, while uploading photo in rails application using paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, factory-bot

This is my factory for photo model

```
factory :photo do
user 
image Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(File.join(Rails.root,'spec','GIV_jpg_file_small.jpg'))
end
```

and this is photo model in which image is the name of column. I am using paperclip gem for images.

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
validates_attachment :image, :presence => true
validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
validates_attachment_size :image, :less_than => 1.megabytes
belongs_to :user
end
```

Now when I run Rspec for this photo model, it is showing

```
Failure/Error: let(:photo) {FactoryGirl.create(:photo)}
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
Validation failed: Image content type is invalid, Image is invalid
```

Can someone fix my problem? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the 2nd argument to `Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new`. It needs to know the content_type. Just add 'image/jpg':

```
image_path = File.join(Rails.root,'spec','GIV_jpg_file_small.jpg')
Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new image_path, 'image/jpg'
```

Comment: Now it is showing this error

Validation failed: Image Could not run the `identify` command. Please install ImageMagick., Image Could not run the `identify` command. Please install ImageMagick.
But I am not using ImageMagick, so do i need to install it?

Comment: You need to install ImageMagick. Are you on Mac? You can run `brew install imagemagick` if you have homebrew. Or read this: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php